# Definition of "worst point one percent"?

Tags: meaning

What does "worst point one" in this sentence mean?

> Stories about the worst point one percent of immigrants.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of OP's incorrect parsing.

Answer (score 9):

I think the article tries to say

> Stories about the worst 0.1% of immigrants.

I may be totally wrong too. But does this fit the context.

Comment: You are correct. The leading zero is often left off as it is implied by nothing preceding "point."